# unable to retrieve data from derby double field through text box param in java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I have  derby table with double field when am calling the table by passing param value through text box I have got error message  stating that
" **Cannot format given Object as a Number**" 
My calling function hereunder :
am searching long time without luck and I  affraid some java and SO expert  tend and used to block any inquiry primary  to them

```
public void  LoadLineFromDatabase() {

          String host1 =  Pathhost; // String host1 = "jdbc:derby://"+ipconfigure.s2+":1527//accountsdb";
           String uName1="accounts";
           String uPass1="accounts";
           String sql1;

    try {
        con1=DriverManager.getConnection(host1,uName1 ,uPass1);
        BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(jTsaleitemNo.getText());

         sql1="select * from items inner join barcodes on barcodes.item=items.item_id Where barcodes.barcode= " +val+ " ";

         stmt1=con1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rs=stmt1.executeQuery(sql1);
  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTblSales.getModel();
    int j=0;
    //double dRtotal=0;
   // double cRtotal=0;
 //  int j=0;
          while (rs.next()) {
             ++j;
           }
           rs.beforeFirst();
           if(j==0){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No record with this barcode No.");
               return;
         }
    while (rs.next()){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Pathhost);
       // الرمز-الصنف-العدد-سعر الوحدة-الجملة
        model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString("item_secprice"), rs.getString("item_secprice"), rs.getString("item_qnt"),rs.getString("item_name"),rs.getString("item_id")});

        } 


    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrmJournal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLS correct No.");
    }

}
```

full error here
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:507)   at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:507)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI$SynthTableCellRenderer.configureValue(SynthTableUI.java:802)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI$SynthTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(SynthTableUI.java:789)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5723)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCell(SynthTableUI.java:683)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paintCells(SynthTableUI.java:580)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.paint(SynthTableUI.java:364)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableUI.update(SynthTableUI.java:275)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Can you show the exact stack trace with its error message in it?

Comment: this is the error message I have got                                                    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
 at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:507) at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:507)

Comment: Can you show more of the stack trace? Can you show **all** of it?

Comment: @BryanPendleton full error added to code above

Comment: Thanks for the full stack trace. Note that the method `LoadLineFromDatabase` isn't in your stack trace anywhere. Perhaps the error is coming from a different part of your program than you think?

Comment: @BryanPendleton thank you for your help and effort i found the error source that i put the jtable data type double in some places and looks database double format and jtbales ones not the same perhaps number of decimal places now i changed all to string inside jtable